# (Why) is the std::binomial_distribution biased for large probabilities p and slow for small n?

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I want to generate binomially distributed random numbers in c++. Speed is a major concern. Not knowing a lot about random number generators, I use the standard libraries' tools. My code looks like something below:

```
#include <random>

static std::random_device random_dev;
static std::mt19937 random_generator{random_dev()};
std::binomial_distribution<int> binomial_generator;

void RandomInit(int s) {
    //I create the generator object here to save time. Does this make sense?
    binomial_generator = std::binomial_distribution<int>(1, 0.5);
    random_generator.seed(s);
}

int binomrand(int n, double p) {
    binomial_generator.param(std::binomial_distribution<int>::param_type(n, p));
    return binomial_generator(random_generator);
}
```

To test my implementation, I have built a cython wrapper and then executed and timed the function from within python. For reference I have also implemented a "stupid" binomial distribution, which just returns the sum of Bernoulli trials.

```
int binomrand2(int n, double p) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if (_Random() < p) //_Random is a thoroughly tested custom random number generator on U[0,1)
            result++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Timing showed that the latter implementation is about 50% faster than the former if `n < 25`. Furthermore, for `p = 0.95`, the former yielded significantly biased results (the mean over 1000000 trials for `n = 40` was `38.23037`; standard deviation is `0.0014`; the result was reproducable with different seeds).

**Is this a (known) issue with the standard library's functions or is my implementation wrong? What could I do to achieve my goal of obtaining accurate results with high efficiency?**

The parameter `n` will mostly be below `100` and smaller values will occur more frequently.

I am open to suggestions outside the realm of the standard library, but I *may* not be able to use external software libraries.

I am using the VC 2019 compiler on 64bit Windows.

**Edit**

I have also tested the bias without using python:

```
double binomrandTest(int n, double p, long long N) {
    long long result = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        result += binomrand(n, p);
    }
    return ((double) result) / ((double) N);
}
```

The result remained biased (`38.228045` for the parameters above, where something like `38.000507` would be expected).

Comment: Can't duplicate on current VC2019. Looks like a bug in the standard lib you are using. I get 38.0013 and 37.9997 on two runs.

Comment: Have you tested this w/o using Python and just straight c++? If that works consider putting in logging code to track state and compare  to c++ only.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's standard library implementation?  If so, then perhaps the following GitHub issue relates to this: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1530

Comment: @PeterO. Yes, I think I am using the MS standard library (I am using the VC 2019 compiler). The issue may be related, but the case is different (`n*p>1` in my case).

Comment: @doug What do you mean by tracking the state? What should I look for? How would I distinguish expected from erroneous behaviour?

Comment: If your issue differs from the reported one, you should report it on the GitHub issues page.  In the meantime, what values of `n` do you expect to encounter in your application?  If it's much greater than 25, I report on a [binomial sampler](https://peteroupc.github.io/randmisc.html#On_a_Binomial_Sampler) from Bringmann/Farach-Colton/Tsai that may be efficient especially for large values of `n`.

Comment: Hash the contents of the mt19937 object and save the hash on each call. Compare sequences with straight c++ and Python call. Zero in on where they differ to find the cause. But this would only be useful if they differ. I get good values with straight c++ but my version is current.  My guess is that somehow the Python version is re-seeding `random_generator` somehow.

Comment: @PeterO. I expect mostly relatively small numbers of n (below 100; the frequency of n values decays with n). I appreciate any advice on which algorithm/library I should use.

Comment: @doug I have tested the code via c++ only and the issue persisted. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I just checked the code on a slightly older VC2019. Same bug you get. Update your VC2019 which will fix it. @PeterO. link was the problem.

Comment: @doug Thanks a lot! An update ov VC solved the bias problem. Unfortunately, the speed problem remained...

Comment: I tested on gcc 10.2.1.  No bias.  But the simple generator is faster for n < 32.  What's interesting is that the speed for the STL generator varies for n in a non-uniform way.  E.g., n = 17 is significantly slower than n = 15, but n = 34 is only slightly slower than 15, and faster than 17.  It's faster to not reset the parameters of the binomial on each call, and a different random generator than mt19937 is also faster.

Comment: In looking at the std lib code, initialization pre-calculates a bunch of values that may be used depending on the n and p. The algorithm in VC2019 comes from Numerical Recipes. There is a cutoff at N<=25 that uses the "stupid" simple algorithm. Agree with @TrentP on not resetting the parameters. Speeds things up a bit as well as the significant rng performance performance impact.

Comment: I didn't look at the gcc libstdc++ code, but I see that the time appears to grow linearly with n up to n=17, which could be explained by it using the simple algorithm up to N<=17.  For N > 17, it appears the time is O(1) or at least grows much slower than O(n).